Can legacy .aspx pages run on .Net Core Application (Version 8.0)
I am converting a legacy .NET Framework application to an ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC web application. There are certain static .aspx pages on the server, which are not part of the .NET application, they are standalone. Reason for them in .aspx is to have include function, this way common menu & footer are centralized.
Now we are converting to .NET Core 8.0. I do not see any option in IIS for those legacy .aspx pages to render along with new ASP.NET Core application.
Ideal solution would be convert them to .html pages, but there are thousands of them. Also their rating in SEO is pretty good, so I can't discard straight away.
Please suggest any approaches, I can get both running on IIS.

This sounds like a very convoluted set-up, even by Web Forms standards. I think you need to start with the end in mind, irrespective of how it was done before.
Since SEO is important, stay away from SPA (Single Page Applications) such as Angular, React and Vue.
ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC can also be hosted on IIS.
You will not have .aspx pages in ASP.NET NET Core. To have a "centralized", aka "common", menu and footer in the older ASP.NET you should have been using master pages. With MVC, the equivalent will be layout files. So you will probably have to bite the bullet and do this manually. There should not be thousands of them; the whole purpose of master pages and layout files is to eliminate this repetition in the first place so this should be seen as time well spent when you migrate.

I agree with your viewpoint... The challenge is these .aspx pages are created by html designer, they do not have any aspx.cs page, they used DreamWeaver to manage them, no coding, onlu Include tag was present. These aspx pages did not had any relation with .Net Coding, so not master page - as these are not part of any .net project. So these code is running without any difficulty along with .NET Framwork code in IIS. Yes agree, it's hightime to retain it. Instead I will start converting in regular .NET Core Static pages.

It doesn't matter that they had no logic; they could still have used master pages with no functionality in the code-behind. They would then have had just one place to add their links rather than thousands. So, going forward use the same concept with layout page(s) for your repetitive static/non-static content.
